# mysql select null values too when reading data from table

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    kol_table.KolID, kol_table.MDMID, kol_table.First_Name, kol_table.Last_Name, kol_table.Mail, kol_table.Address, 
    kol_table.City, kol_table.State, kol_table.Zip, profile_status_master_table.ProfleStatus,
    degree_master_table.Degree, speciality_master_table.SpecialityName, images.Image_Link
    FROM
 kol_table, degree_master_table, kol_degree_map_table, 
 speciality_master_table, kol_speciality_map_table, 
 profile_status_master_table, images
    WHERE (kol_table.kolID = kol_degree_map_table.KOLID and
           kol_degree_map_table.DegreeID = degree_master_table.DegreeID and kol_table.kolID = KOL_ID)
    AND (kol_table.kolID = kol_speciality_map_table.kolID and 
         kol_speciality_map_table.SpecialtyID = speciality_master_table.SpecialityID )
    AND (kol_table.Profile_Status = profile_status_master_table.ProfileStatusID)
    AND (kol_table.mdmID = images.MDMID);
```

I have this code in this  `kol_degree_map_table.DegreeID`  I have `id` which is referenced from  `degree_master_table.DegreeID` and I also have some `null` values in `kol_degree_map_table` which is want to include when I'm selecting the data but I dont know how to. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Please review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your question. Please read [**How to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit and revise your question here. Thanks.

Comment: If you want null change comma joins to left joins (actually forget comma joins entirely and use explicit joins which are far more readable) Also readability could be improved by assigning aliases to tables.

Comment: @P.Salmon absolutely a good idea, but the only qualifier here is if there are null values in the `kol_table` row data. But I'm not diving into that until I can be sure of what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The OPs Query rewritten using proper standard SQL ANSI syntax is below.  As others have stated definitely never write a query using those comma joins.  I've found only a few instances where using comma joins can be useful but this answer isn't about that. Read [THIS](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618) post to get more information on why we don't write queries using comma joins.  This will help you begin to write better queries that are easy to read. You can tell what the JOINs are vs the Query filters in the WHERE Clause when using standard syntax.

After rewriting the query it is easy to see that there are zero filters and each condition the OP had in the WHERE clause are all actually JOIN Conditions and so it was easy to rewrite.  No filters in the WHERE Clause.  Lastly, each table now has an alias making it so much easier to read.

```
SELECT 
    kt.KolID, kt.MDMID, kt.First_Name, kt.Last_Name, kt.Mail, kt.Address, 
    kt.City, kt.State, kt.Zip, psmt.ProfleStatus,
    dmt.Degree, smt.SpecialityName, i.Image_Link
FROM
    kol_table kt
    JOIN kol_degree_map_table          mp ON mp.kolid             = kt.kolid
    JOIN kol_speciality_map_table    ksmt ON ksmt.kolID           = kt.kolID
    JOIN degree_master_table          dmt ON dmt.DegreeID         = mp.DegreeID
    JOIN speciality_master_table      smt ON smt.SpecialityID     = ksmt.SpecialtyID
    JOIN profile_status_master_table psmt ON psmt.ProfileStatusID = kt.Profile_Statua
    JOIN images                         i ON i.MDMID              = kt.mdmID
    
--WHERE 
    --(
        --kt.kolID = mp.KOLID AND -- Moved to a JOIN Condition
        -- mp.DegreeID = dmt.DegreeID  AND  -- Moved to a JOIN Condition
        --  kt.kolID = KOL_ID -- This field doesn't have a table.  What table does KOL_ID in this condition come from???
    --) AND
     
    --(
        --kt.kolID = ksmt.kolID   -- Moved to a JOIN Condition AND
        --ksmt.SpecialtyID = smt.SpecialityID -- Moved to a JOIN Condition
    --) AND
    
    -- (kt.Profile_Status = psmt.ProfileStatusID) AND -- Moved to a JOIN Condition
    
    -- (kt.mdmID = i.MDMID) -- Moved to a JOIN Condition
;
```

I found one issue with the original query and that is I don't know what table one of the original conditions is referring to and I have made a note on that line in the comment seen in the above query. `kt.kolID = KOL_ID`

The OP originally asked how they could still get NULLs out of the kol_degree_map_table.  This table is basically the 2nd table in the chain of JOINs and so if NO records tie back to this table from the kol_table we would also lose our records  the degree_master_table due to it also joining on the kol_degree_map_table.  If the OP truly wants to still see the kol_table records that don't have a JOIN to the kol_degree_map_table we need to LEFT JOIN this as well as adding a LEFT JOIN to any tables that join back to to this table.

New version below with LEFT JOINs added answering the OPs question as best I can.

```
SELECT 
    kt.KolID, kt.MDMID, kt.First_Name, kt.Last_Name, kt.Mail, kt.Address, 
    kt.City, kt.State, kt.Zip, psmt.ProfleStatus,
    dmt.Degree, smt.SpecialityName, i.Image_Link
FROM
    kol_table kt
    LEFT JOIN kol_degree_map_table          mp ON mp.kolid             = kt.kolid
    LEFT JOIN kol_speciality_map_table         ksmt ON ksmt.kolID           = kt.kolID
    LEFT JOIN degree_master_table               dmt ON dmt.DegreeID         = mp.DegreeID
    LEFT JOIN speciality_master_table           smt ON smt.SpecialityID     = ksmt.SpecialtyID
    LEFT JOIN profile_status_master_table      psmt ON psmt.ProfileStatusID = kt.Profile_Statua
    LEFT JOIN images                              i ON i.MDMID              = kt.mdmID
```

Comment: Oracle comma+(+) for left join is not standard SQL but that is not a reason to criticize standard comma or to misrepresent standard comma as Oracle comma+(+).

Comment: It is though... the Oracle comma joins and the use of the + syntaxes are old and outdated. My last company we made an effort to remove that syntax in our downtime and anytime we encountered it. We never excepted any new sql in our codebase if it were submitted having that syntax. I work in sql server now and so new issues and completely different.

Comment: I don't know how you can think that non-standard comma-plus-(+) existing can have any bearing on arguments about standard comma, which doesn't have (+). Not sure you got the point of my last comment. I didn't say anything about comma-plus-(+) except that it wasn't standard SQL. (It was always a bad way to try to denote outer joins.)

Comment: Do you understand from my earlier comment that I just deleted that your adding LEFT does not change what the query ever returns--a later INNER JOIN's ON removes any nulls introduced because it requires a column of the right table to be SQL = to something, ie to be non-null. "left join is turned into inner join" Also: The question post says "I also have some null values in kol_degree_map_table which [I] want to include" but your ONs all remove them. But you need something like OR IS NULL, LEFT per se doesn't help, it doesn't keep input nulls any more or less than INNER.

Comment: (An illustration of why debug questions require a [mre] or be closed, ie have answers blocked.)

Comment: Yes you are correct about the inner joins. Much appreciated I'll fix those next time I am able to. Without actual data to test I did miss that fact. Good catch.